# Is there a way to erase my personal data without losing my apps?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, sync, delete

I have an ADP1 running 2.2.1, and used it with my Google Account. I have to give it to a friend, and want to erase all my personal data viz. email, chat logs, photos in the gallery synced with picasa, and any other stuff that might be synced. But the problem is, I do not want to lose the apps. Is there a way to erase my data, without losing the apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backup your apps using Astro File Manager or MyBackupPro or Titanium Backup.

THEN perform a Factory reset to wipe everything.

Finally, from the backups, restore the Apps, but NOT the data. (Most backup apps allow you to do this.)

Be warned that some apps store data on the storage card, so a fresh install might still pick up the old data off your SD card. Be sure to erase your SD Card too.

Answer (score 0):

Every program under 'Settings' - 'Applications' , 'Manage applications' has, when clicked a 'Clear data' button.

This should do what you want.

As far as I know, you will have to be rooted to have a program does this for you.

Comment: Note that the "Clear data" does not remove the account(s) in "Accounts & sync".